# Purge Abandoned Change-Ids from Gerrit for good

Tags: gerrit

On Gerrit Web UI, I do not see a way to purge `Change-Ids` in `"Abandoned"` state.
While trying out `Gerrit` we created a good number of `Change-Ids` that are required to go 
away from the Web UI.

Is cleaning from DB directly using SQL scripts, the only alternative?

Gerrit: version 2.4.2
OS: RedHat Based

Please let me know if you require any additional information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, purging the DB is the only way (currently) to completely delete changes.  They also will still exist in the repository under the refs/changes/ branch, but won't show up in the Web UI once the database has been purged.